# How to optimize / speed-up this code, so i can handle a big dataset?

Tags: vba

I am working in a "Big" excel dataset, and have to find unique values within a range and use that information to get: Mean, Std deviation, Median, Min and Max.

So the code below work but i need to "loop" through 41000 (x). So it will be a bit heavy, so before i try that is there anything that can be done in term of optimization?

Thank you!

```
Sub Finddata()
Dim Startdate As Date
Dim Finalrow As Long
Dim EndDate As Date
Dim Targetperiod As Integer
Dim Company As String
Dim i As Long
Dim d As Integer
Dim x As Long
Dim duplicaterow As Integer
Dim Newduplicaterow As Integer
Dim SourceBook As Workbook
Dim Datasheet As Worksheet, Duplicatesheet As Worksheet

Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayStatusBar = False
Application.EnableEvents = False

Set SourceBook = ActiveWorkbook
Set Datasheet = SourceBook.Sheets("Data")
Set Duplicatesheet = SourceBook.Sheets("Duplicate sheet")

Finalrow = Datasheet.Range("A60000").End(xlUp).Row


For x = 2 To 10

Startdate = Datasheet.Range("r" & x)
EndDate = Datasheet.Range("q" & x)
Company = Datasheet.Range("p" & x)
Targetperiod = Datasheet.Range("i" & x)


'Copy data to duplicate sheet
For i = 2 To Finalrow
    If (Cells(i, 17) >= Startdate And Cells(i, 17) <= EndDate And Cells(i, 16) = Company And Cells(i, 9) = Targetperiod) Then
    Range(Cells(i, 1), Cells(i, 19)).Copy
    Duplicatesheet.Range("a10000").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 21).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    Duplicatesheet.Range("a10000").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    End If
Next i

'Definition
duplicaterow = Duplicatesheet.Range("v10000").End(xlUp).Row

'Removes duplicate analyst names
Duplicatesheet.Range("v1", "an" & duplicaterow).RemoveDuplicates Columns:=14, Header:=xlYes

'Definition
Newduplicaterow = Duplicatesheet.Range("v10000").End(xlUp).Row + 1

'Removes two columns that are not needed
Duplicatesheet.Range("Am:An").EntireColumn.Delete

'Below is for finding most recent observation and Target price.
d = 2

Do While Duplicatesheet.Cells(d, 38).Value <> ""
    Duplicatesheet.Cells(d, 39).FormulaLocal = "=MAX(IF('Duplicate sheet'!n:n='Duplicate sheet'!Ai" & d & ";'Duplicate sheet'!q:q;))"
    d = d + 1
Loop

  Dim c As Range
  For Each c In Duplicatesheet.Range("Am2", "am" & Newduplicaterow)
    c.FormulaArray = c.FormulaR1C1
  Next c

d = 2

Do While Duplicatesheet.Cells(d, 38).Value <> ""
    Duplicatesheet.Cells(d, 39).Value = Duplicatesheet.Cells(d, 39).Value
    Duplicatesheet.Cells(d, 40).Value = Duplicatesheet.Cells(d, 35) & ", " & Duplicatesheet.Cells(d, 39)
    d = d + 1
Loop

d = 2

Do While Duplicatesheet.Cells(d, 38).Value <> ""
    Duplicatesheet.Cells(d, 41).FormulaLocal = "=index('Duplicate sheet'!d:d;match('Duplicate sheet'!AN" & d & ";'Duplicate sheet'!s:s;0);0)"
    Duplicatesheet.Cells(d, 41).Value = Duplicatesheet.Cells(d, 41).Value
    d = d + 1
Loop


'This section creates the values that are needed in the data sheet, for consensus
Duplicatesheet.Range("v" & Newduplicaterow + 1).Offset(0, 0).FormulaLocal = "=Average(AO2:AO" & Newduplicaterow - 1 & ")"
Duplicatesheet.Range("v" & Newduplicaterow + 1).Offset(0, 1).FormulaLocal = "=iferror(STDEV.S(AO2:AO" & Newduplicaterow - 1 & ");count(AO2:AO" & Newduplicaterow - 1 & "))"
Duplicatesheet.Range("v" & Newduplicaterow + 1).Offset(0, 2).FormulaLocal = "=MEDIAN(AO2:AO" & Newduplicaterow - 1 & ")"
Duplicatesheet.Range("v" & Newduplicaterow + 1).Offset(0, 3).FormulaLocal = "=Min(AO2:AO" & Newduplicaterow - 1 & ")"
Duplicatesheet.Range("v" & Newduplicaterow + 1).Offset(0, 4).FormulaLocal = "=max(AO2:AO" & Newduplicaterow - 1 & ")"
Duplicatesheet.Range("v" & Newduplicaterow + 1).Offset(0, 0).Value = Duplicatesheet.Range("v" & Newduplicaterow + 1).Offset(0, 0).Value
Duplicatesheet.Range("v" & Newduplicaterow + 1).Offset(0, 1).Value = Duplicatesheet.Range("v" & Newduplicaterow + 1).Offset(0, 1).Value
Duplicatesheet.Range("v" & Newduplicaterow + 1).Offset(0, 2).Value = Duplicatesheet.Range("v" & Newduplicaterow + 1).Offset(0, 2).Value
Duplicatesheet.Range("v" & Newduplicaterow + 1).Offset(0, 3).Value = Duplicatesheet.Range("v" & Newduplicaterow + 1).Offset(0, 3).Value
Duplicatesheet.Range("v" & Newduplicaterow + 1).Offset(0, 4).Value = Duplicatesheet.Range("v" & Newduplicaterow + 1).Offset(0, 4).Value

Duplicatesheet.Range("v" & Newduplicaterow + 1, "z" & Newduplicaterow + 1).Copy
Datasheet.Range("t" & x).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

Duplicatesheet.Range("A2:BB6000").ClearContents

Next x


Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.DisplayStatusBar = True
Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

Comment: You can speed up almost everything by using assembler / C / C++. VBA is based on .Net. Like C#. Very much overhead to no use at all ...

Comment: The answer to optimizing speed is to always use a  dictionary for lookups and arrays for reading and more importantly writing values.   StackOverflow is for code that doesn't work.  Questions about optimization should be posted on [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: @peakpeak Could you provide an example?

Comment: @TinMan You mean a complete working code example of how you can write your VBA code in assembler?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's difficult to say without seeing the structure and layout of your data and workbook (in case there is a simpler/more efficient way to what you're doing). But below are some basic observations.

---

You should probably be using `Range.AutoFilter` below (instead of looping through tens of thousands of rows one row at a time). Then copy-paste `Range.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)` to your `duplicateSheet` in one go. You may need to convert your dates to doubles (with `CDbl()` function) when specifying date filter criteria. (You could also read into an array once. Performance may be faster with an array, but you'd also have to write more code.)

```
    'Copy data to duplicate sheet
    For i = 2 To finalRow
        If (Cells(i, 17) >= startDate And Cells(i, 17) <= EndDate And Cells(i, 16) = Company And Cells(i, 9) = Targetperiod) Then
            Range(Cells(i, 1), Cells(i, 19)).Copy
            duplicateSheet.Range("a10000").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 21).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
            duplicateSheet.Range("a10000").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        End If
    Next i
```

---

Below, you assign what should be an array formula as a non-array formula to each cell in column `AM` (one row at a time); then perform the loop again (one row at a time) to turn the non-array formula into an array formula; then perform the loop again (one row at a time) to turn the formulas into static values.

Is there a reason why you can't set an array formula for the entire range in one go? I believe Excel will take care of relative cell references for you. Then turn said range's formulas into static values. (Alternatively, you could read the range's values into an array, and calculate the conditional `MAX` in memory. But as said before, you'll need to write more code.)

Also, some newer versions of Excel natively have a `MAXIFS` function. If you have access to it, try using that. Another observation is that your array formula refers to the entire column. Might be worth limiting the range (i.e. to the last used row in that column), so you're only looking at <100k cells (for example) instead of 1 million.

Last point is that concatenation of strings can be costly. Generally, you want to use some form of `JOIN` function when concatenating, though am not sure how much it will benefit performance here as you're only concatenating two values (per loop iteration).

```
    'Below is for finding most recent observation and Target price.
    d = 2

    Do While duplicateSheet.Cells(d, 38).Value <> ""
        duplicateSheet.Cells(d, 39).FormulaLocal = "=MAX(IF('Duplicate sheet'!n:n='Duplicate sheet'!Ai" & d & ";'Duplicate sheet'!q:q;))"
        d = d + 1
    Loop

    Dim c As Range
    For Each c In duplicateSheet.Range("Am2", "am" & Newduplicaterow)
      c.FormulaArray = c.FormulaR1C1
    Next c

    d = 2

    Do While duplicateSheet.Cells(d, 38).Value <> ""
        duplicateSheet.Cells(d, 39).Value = duplicateSheet.Cells(d, 39).Value
        duplicateSheet.Cells(d, 40).Value = duplicateSheet.Cells(d, 35) & ", " & duplicateSheet.Cells(d, 39)
        d = d + 1
    Loop
```

---

You could probably assign the formula below to the entire range in one go. One thing to note is that providing `0` as `MATCH`'s third argument means you're performing a linear search (for each loop iteration). Consider using a dictionary or collection for a faster lookup (dictionary is probably more convenient as it has an `Exists` method). In your case, I think values in column `S` would be the keys and values in column `D` would be the keys' corresponding values.

Also, you can convert the entire range to static values in one go (rather than looping one row at a time).

```
    d = 2

    Do While duplicateSheet.Cells(d, 38).Value <> ""
        duplicateSheet.Cells(d, 41).FormulaLocal = "=index('Duplicate sheet'!d:d;match('Duplicate sheet'!AN" & d & ";'Duplicate sheet'!s:s;0);0)"
        duplicateSheet.Cells(d, 41).Value = duplicateSheet.Cells(d, 41).Value
        d = d + 1
    Loop
```

---

Hopefully this gives you some ideas on where to start.